# LinearLayout in HorizontalScrollView is not expanding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have this custom HorizontalScrollView that dynamically builds the following layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView width=match_parent>

      <LinearLayout width=match_parent horizontal>
            // here TextViews are dinamycally added
      </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

so whenever I need to update the TextViews, what is actually done is `removeAllViews()` in the LinearLayout and they are re-created and re-added.

The TextViews have a padding of a some DP and `setLines(1);`. When adding them to the LinearLayout, they're being added with `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, WRAP_CONTENT, 1f)` (zero width, but weight=1).

The objective here is that if the TextViews are smaller than the screen width they will expand to fit the screen and if they're bigger than the screen width they will be `padding + text lenght + padding` and scroll horizontally in the screen.

It almost works except in some edge cases. Examples:

**Works**: I have 5 TextViews with a couple of short/medium words on each. All layouts nicely and you can scroll through them

**Works**: I have 2 TextViews with a couple of short/medium words on each. The TextViews expands to fill the screen and the text is centered on them.

**Fail**: I have 3 TextViews with the following texts: `1 lorem` | `43 consectetur` | `20 dolor` the layout will simply match the screen width and the word "consectetur" will disappear (trying to go to the next line). Similar fails for different size words or numbers.

I tried `requestLayout`, `invalidate`, `setVisibility(GONE);setVisibility(VISIBLE)` `updateViewLayout`, `setFillViewport(true);` and trick out the layout weight of the TextViews based on the text lenght. All with no luck.

Does anyone knows how I could make this work without having to re-write the onMeasure of the LinearLayout (which I checked it's a total of 381 lines for the Horizontal version)

Comment: Did you try setting your TextView to be multiline in case they have bigger texts android:inputType="textMultiLine" or setInputType(TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE )?

Comment: set singleline true for the textview, or you can show it multiline

Comment: @AtulOHolic I'm calling `setLines(1);` proposital. It must be just one line.

Comment: @Ari thanks man. adding `textView.setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());` did the trick. I still have to check more in different languages and different values, but as far as I can see it seems to be working.

Comment: can you please upvote my comment if you really think it was useful.

Comment: you can also write it as an actual answer and I can mark it as correct.